# Sharepoint, Create View, Filter Properties

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to create a view in Sharepoint that has a filter based on a date field.

The filter should be >= Today and <- Today + 90 days.

I found a reference to the

```
<Today OffsetDays=”5” />
```

CAML function and could probably use this by setting the view using the API.

My question is how do i set this using the browser based admin page?

[alt text http://www.isuppli.com/Img/Development/CreateViewSample.gif](http://www.isuppli.com/Img/Development/CreateViewSample.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done OTB using the filter dropdowns when modifying or creating a view:

[Filter Image](http://img91.imageshack.us/my.php?image=filterew5.png)

[alt text http://img91.imageshack.us/my.php?image=filterew5.png](http://img91.imageshack.us/my.php?image=filterew5.png)

Edit: Fixed image

Comment: I think your second condition should be updated - it says that the created date is greater than today + 90 -- it should be *less than*.

Comment: I thought I had already fixed that.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think you have to ensure that there are no spaces between [Today]+90 - seriously, you will get an error about invalid formula if there are spaces in!

Answer (score 0):

Ok... when you using formula for the column...
It cant using [Today] because it doesnt exsist on the list column...]

So i suggest that you must required the column Today first, so you can use [Today] At the formula..

i think u just dont have using CAML or column formula, but it can do from filtering like AdamBT says...

Hehehe...

Comment: You can use [Today] in a filter without doing anyting - you cant using it in calculated columns. Don#t event start on the Today trick...
http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/